# how to sort contours function from right to left and read it in multiple line

Tags: python

I want this code to sort it from right to left and also can read it in multiple line, I have tried a lot of codes and they are changing the predict result.

this code for calling sort_contours function

```
 cnts, boundingBoxes_sorted = sort_contours(cnts, method="right-to-left")
```

and this code for sort the contours

```
def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
    try:
      reverse = False
      i = 0
      if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
          reverse = True
      if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
          i = 1
      boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
      (cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
      key=lambda b:b[1][i], reverse=reverse))
    except Exception as e:
      print("ُُError")
    return (cnts, boundingBoxes)
```

I want to sort it like this image
[sort image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0POe.png)

I apologies for my English language, I really need help can you please help me